# How to code characters in Web.Config by Unicode value

Tags: c#, asp.net, unicode

In ASP.net, using a WEB.CONFIG file with an appSettings section;  I am trying to store some string variables.  One is a string containing a non breaking space (unicode hex value 00A0), and the other is an empty string.

I am thinking it is something like "#&FFFF" for unicode, but can't find any guidance on this.  Also, the WEB.CONFIG file does not like an empty string.

I have a workaround for this, but it would be great to know how to store unicode characters or empty strings in the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web.config is XML so follow the [XML standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping)

`<add key="Test" value="&#xa0;" />`